# Can't query database using the generated models from sequelize-auto

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I followed the instructions on how to generate models from an existing database as pointed here https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto. However when I try to query the database using the model i get this error:

**TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
at Function.keys ()
at Function.findAll (/home/jefry/node/sequelize/node_modules/sequelize/src/model.js:1755:47)
at /home/jefry/node/sequelize/src/components/users/controllers.ts:11:32
at Generator.next ()
at /home/jefry/node/sequelize/src/components/users/controllers.ts:31:71
at new Promise ()
at __awaiter (/home/jefry/node/sequelize/src/components/users/controllers.ts:27:12)
at list (/home/jefry/node/sequelize/src/components/users/controllers.ts:45:12)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/jefry/node/sequelize/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/home/jefry/node/sequelize/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)**

**Controller***

```
export async function list(req: Request, res: Response) {
  try {
    const list = await primera.findAll();
    res.json({ list });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

**Model***

```
import * as Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import { DataTypes, Model, Optional } from 'sequelize';

export interface primeraAttributes {
  verdad?: number;
}

export type primeraOptionalAttributes = "verdad";
export type primeraCreationAttributes = Optional<primeraAttributes, primeraOptionalAttributes>;

export class primera extends Model<primeraAttributes, primeraCreationAttributes> implements primeraAttributes {
  verdad?: number;


  static initModel(sequelize: Sequelize.Sequelize): typeof primera {
    return primera.init({
    verdad: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: true
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'primera',
    timestamps: false
  });
  }
}
```

**init-models**

```
import type { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import { primera as _primera } from "./primera";
import type { primeraAttributes, primeraCreationAttributes } from "./primera";

export {
  _primera as primera,
};

export type {
  primeraAttributes,
  primeraCreationAttributes,
};

export function initModels(sequelize: Sequelize) {
  const primera = _primera.initModel(sequelize);


  return {
    primera: primera,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass at least an empty object as an argument of `findAll`:

```js
const list = await primera.findAll({});
```